# Typo3 8.7.x / CKEditor: How to override the labels of the headlines in dropdown list?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to override the labels of the headlines in dropdown list. I tried the following yaml config, but it's not working:

```
editor:
  config:
    format_h2: { name: "test", element: "h1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by myself, hope it helps someone else:
You can create remove the standard headlines from format_tags and add custom ones like headline1;headline2,...

```
editor:
  config:
    format_tags: 'p;headline1;headline2;headline3'
    format_headline1: { element: 'h1', name: 'Very Large Headline' }
    format_headline2: { element: 'h2', name: 'Large Headline' }
    format_headline3: { element: 'h3', name: 'Normal Headline' }
```